# Webpack Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, eslint

I am using a mix of Webpack/Babel 6/React/eslint. based on the answers that I have seen, I have all of the required dependencies. My eslint config contains the following:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
        "modules": true
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to find a solution for this. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Where/when does the error occur? When you run eslint? Which version and parser are you using for eslint? We need a lot more information here.

Comment: Based on my research, I have surmised that eslint (v2.4.0) is the culprit. To my knowledge, I am not using a parser. Please expound as I am not an eslint expert. The error occurs in index.js. I'm a bit flabbergasted because I seem to have all of the necessary pieces in place. I understand that I may not be giving the best complex. At this point, I am giving all of the info that I have.

Comment: Here's a working set of packages that I use https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater/blob/develop/ui/package.json I had to get `babel-eslint@6.0.0-beta.6 to get eslint 2.4 to work. config if it matters https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater/blob/develop/ui/.eslintrc.json

Comment: show your webpack configuration.  Show the full error message, including the source file and line number

Comment: @azium: *"I had to get `babel-eslint@6.0.0-beta.6 to get eslint 2.4 to work."* Using babel-eslint is only necessary if you are using features that are not support by the default eslint parser (which are not that many). That doesn't seem to be related to the issues the OP is facing.

Comment: Webpack Config: https://gist.github.com/danawhite/ef2570c1caab3c0104149b3fb40aadda Error stack trace: `ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/danawhite/dev/admin-dashboard/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1745:13)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/danawhite/dev/admin-dashboard/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2450:3...`. It's basically complaining about import statements. I installed babel-eslint to no avail.

Comment: That's your package.json? Not your `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: True Webpack config: https://gist.github.com/danawhite/8ae3d2962f708a5b68c0d2adf14e8a70. I neglected to mention that I began having this issue when I installed brfs and transform-loader to use a browserify transform in Webpack. This became a necessity as a result of a dependency in the **shopify-api-node** module. The Shopify module is necessary for my work and there seems to be no way around it at the moment.

Comment: @azium Here's my .babelrc for good measure: `{
    "presets":[
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": []
}`